# Plot second y axis using plot and fill (without plotyy)

Tags: matlab, plot, multiple-axes

Here is my code

```
clear all;clc
x = linspace(0, 10, 100);

axes('Position', [.075,.075,.9,.2], ...
     'XColor',   'k', ...
     'YColor',   [0 0 0]);
fill(x, circshift(sin(x), 50), 'red', 'EdgeColor','None');
ylabel('Fancy Sine', 'FontSize', 11);

% Adding this the upper vanishes and the y axes is on left not right side
axes('Position',      [.075,.075,.9,.2], ...
     'XColor',        'k', ...
     'YAxisLocation', 'Right', ...
     'Color',         'none');
plot(x, x, 'Color', [.2 .4 .8]);
ylabel('Line Graph', 'FontSize', 11);

xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 11);
```

The single axis works fine

[image]

But when I want to add the second axis, the first disappears and the new axis is not on the right, but left side..

[image]

But both plots should be in one axis and the second y axis should be on the right side.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot` automatically sets the axis properties to the default. Use `hold` to stop this or specify the axis properties after your `plot` call.

An example of the former:

```
clear all;clc
x = linspace(0, 10, 100);

ax1 = axes('Position', [.075,.075,.9,.2], ...
     'XColor',   'k', ...
     'YColor',   [0 0 0]);
p1 = fill(x, circshift(sin(x), 50), 'red', 'EdgeColor','None','Parent',ax1);
ylabel('Fancy Sine', 'FontSize', 11);

% Adding this the upper vanishes and the y axes is on left not right side
ax2 = axes('Position',      [.075,.075,.9,.2], ...
     'XColor',        'k', ...
     'YAxisLocation', 'Right', ...
     'Color',         'none');
hold on
p2 = plot(ax2,x, x, 'Color', [.2 .4 .8]);
hold off
ylabel('Line Graph', 'FontSize', 11);
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 11);
```

Edit1: The reason you don't need to do this for your `fill` call is because it creates a `patch` object in your axes and does not invoke a `plot` command.

Comment: beat me by 4 seconds. :)

Comment: Any way of hiding the second x axis  completely? `XColor` - `none` doesn't work..

Comment: @embert `set(ax2,'Xtick',[])` and shift the `xlabel` call before your second `axes` call so it looks better.